# JDBC - XAMPP (MySQL db) - Connection problem through internet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, xampp

How to connect MySQL db from another computer through internet. Where we can specify
the configurations. my.ini does not work?

Answer (score 0):

you should know your db's public ip address and then configure your db's router, you can find there the port forwarding you can accept all incoming ports. Did you configure your db that allows remote connection? and then check your .cnf file and then check the bind-address. Hope this helps.